# python code output not showing on windows 10 terminal

Tags: python

I typed this code to make a ping pong game. But when I run the code, the terminal does not show the two paddles I made.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen() 
wn.title("Pong By Samuel Hwang")
wn._bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

while True:
    wn.update()

paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)
```

What did I do wrong there?

Comment: don't post photos of code. the people who will help you will also want to try to run the code to experiment with solutions. do you expect them to re-type everything?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and where you think the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your **while loop to the end**!

```
while (True):
    wn.update()
```

I don't see how any of your code could execute when this loop doesn't seem to finish.